# Hidden pdf form fields get displayed when using DynaPDF 3.0 for merging PDFs

Tags: php, pdf

recently I found that one of the php based systems I have to code plugins for updated
it's DynaPDF lib version from 2.0 to 3.0. One thing I do is merging two pdf files into
one.

The first pdf is a plain pdf, no form fields, just text and images. The second pdf
contains a feedback form that can post its content to a certain url. I have two
text fields on there and three hidden fields as well.

Now, everything works fine besides the fact that the hidden form fields are 
perfectly visible ( i.e. nonHidden ;) ) on the finally merged PDF file.

Did somebody also stumble into this kind of issue with DynaPDF?

thanks,

K

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the reverse? Add pdf2 first and then pdf1. How about using pdfAddFieldToHideAction to add the hidden fields specifically again?